# I stored an array in a text file. I want to compare that array (which is in the text file) to another array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array

```
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', ...., 'NameN']
```

this array is stored in a .txt file, exactly like that.

Now in my code, I am trying to compare that array in the file with another array that's not stored in a file.

When I read the txt file array the type is a string, if I convert it to list I will get this

```
["['Name1'", " 'Name2' ", " 'Name3' ", ..... 'NameN']"]
```

Just curious, how do I read that txt file array and make it look like `['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', ...., 'NameN']`

Thanks

Comment: *How*  do you "convert it to a list"  currently ...

Comment: Also note that a list is not an array. They do similar things, but they are different. https://learnpython.com/blog/python-array-vs-list/

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: You should be aware about the security of *Python eval()* on *untrusted strings*!

Example of ***eval()*** function:

```
input_string="['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3','NameN']"
result=eval(input_string)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'NameN']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're reading files, Python automatically transforms text file's contents to a list of strings. If you use `readlines()` for example, you will create a list of strings, each string from that list being a single line of text from your text file.

Python by itself cannot convert string to a list, what you could do is use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module, then use `ast.literal_eval()` function to transform input string to actual data type, note that the string has to be a correct Python data type (list, set, tuple or dictionary), if it's not the interpreter will raise an exception.

[ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function takes any string as parameter.

Example:

```
import ast

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
   f_contents = f.readlines()
   lists = []
   
   for line in f_contents:
        lists.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

This piece of code will:

1. Open your text file and read contents
2. Each line of text inside the file will be added as an string to `f_conents` list
3. Create an empty list of lists, this will contain all valid lists from your `f_contents` list
4. For loop that will read through every line of text from `f_contents` and convert it from a string to a proper Python list using `ast.literal_eval()`

EDIT: Forgot to mention, there's also [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function as mentioned by another answer, however `eval()` is considered to be unsafe. `ast.literal_eval()` accepts only strings that are identical to a data type in Python, it will throw an exception if input is not a list, dict or tuple; where **eval** can interpret any command whether it's malicious or not, it's functionality can be abused so it's recommended to not use with user input.

Answer (score 0):

> Array.txt -> `['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']`

> yourArray -> `['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']`

```
def compareArrays(StoredArrayLocation,yourArray):
    with open(StoredArrayLocation, "r") as f:
        storedData = f.read()    
        x=[]
        x=storedData
        f.close()
        #print(x)
    if x==yourArray:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

```
compareArrays("Array.txt",yourArray)
```

> Output: `True`